# Deleting N items from a collection view section prevents last N items being reloaded in same batch

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uikit

Edit: Upon further testing this is not performing the update on iOS 15.2, but does update on iOS 13.0 and 14.0, so this appears to be an iOS bug!

I'm trying to apply batch updates to a `UICollectionView` but I'm finding that for every `N` items in a section that are deleted `N` items at the end of the section will ignore any reloads.

I have an example `UICollectionView`:

```swift
import UIKit

final class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    var data: [[String]] = []

    var requestedIndexPaths: [IndexPath] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionView.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "UICollectionViewCell")

        applyInitialData(
            [
                ["0, 0", "0, 1", "0, 2", "0, 3", "0, 4", "0, 5", "0, 6", "0, 7"],
            ]
        )

        let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(reloadAll), for: .valueChanged)
        collectionView.refreshControl = refreshControl
    }

    @objc
    private func reloadAll() {
        collectionView.reloadData()
        collectionView.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
    }

    func applyInitialData(_ data: [[String]]) {
        self.data = data
        loadViewIfNeeded()
        collectionView.reloadData()
        collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
        requestedIndexPaths = []
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        requestedIndexPaths.append(indexPath)
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "UICollectionViewCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.contentView.subviews.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() }
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = data[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        cell.contentView.addSubview(label)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.topAnchor),
            label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.leadingAnchor),
        ])
        return cell
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        data.count
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        data[section].count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.size.width, height: 40)
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt: IndexPath) {
        updateUsingReload()
//        updateUsingInsertAndDelete()
    }

    /// With this method 0, 6 will not be updated until pull-to-refresh is used.
    private func updateUsingReload() {
        collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
            data[0][0] = "0, 0 (updated)"
            data[0][1] = "0, 1 (updated)"
            data[0][4] = "0, 4 (updated)"
            data[0][5] = "0, 5 (updated)"
            data[0][6] = "0, 6 (updated)"
            data[0].remove(at: 3)
            data[0].remove(at: 2)
            collectionView.deleteItems(at: [
                IndexPath(item: 2, section: 0),
                IndexPath(item: 3, section: 0),
            ])
            collectionView.reloadItems(at: [
                IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0),
                IndexPath(item: 1, section: 0),
                IndexPath(item: 4, section: 0),
                IndexPath(item: 5, section: 0),
                IndexPath(item: 6, section: 0),
            ])
        })
    }

    /// With this method all cells will be reloaded, but the animation is not as
    /// nice because the cells are not really removed.
    private func updateUsingInsertAndDelete() {
        collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
            data[0][0] = "0, 0 (updated)"
            data[0][1] = "0, 1 (updated)"
            data[0][4] = "0, 4 (updated)"
            data[0][5] = "0, 5 (updated)"
            data[0][6] = "0, 6 (updated)"
            data[0].remove(at: 3)
            data[0].remove(at: 2)
            collectionView.deleteItems(at: [
                IndexPath(item: 2, section: 0),
                IndexPath(item: 3, section: 0),
                IndexPath(item: 4, section: 0),
                IndexPath(item: 5, section: 0),
                IndexPath(item: 6, section: 0),
            ])
            collectionView.insertItems(at: [
                // 2 items have really been deleted, these item use the "after"
                // indexes and are 4, 5, and 6 prior to the update.
                IndexPath(item: 2, section: 0),
                IndexPath(item: 3, section: 0),
                IndexPath(item: 4, section: 0),
            ])
            collectionView.reloadItems(at: [
                IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0),
                IndexPath(item: 1, section: 0),
            ])
        })
    }
}
```

When I tap a cell (to trigger the updates) the `0, 6` cell does not update. Using the `updateUsingInsertAndDelete` function instead does reload all the cells, but there's no delete animation like there is when using `updateUsingReload`.

I have this example in a full project at https://github.com/JosephDuffy/CollectionViewTesting.

Comment: You have deleted items 2 and 3, so items 5 and 6 aren't there any more. You have items 1,2,3,4.

Comment: Calling `reloadItems` with items 2 and 3 caused a crash due to reloading and deleting the same index path, which points to the reloads being processed before the deletes. Calling `reloadItems` with 0, 1, and 5 also reloads 0, 1, and 5 (from the "before" perspective), which backs up that thinking.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use reloadItems (or reconfigureItems) to reload items which was moved. Seems like reloadItems assume the items in question are keeping their positions during update. It looks like there is no way to animate and update item at the same time.

You can either update item after it was moved or try to implement custom cell animation using `collectionView.cellForItem(at:)`